# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a slider but keep getting this error.

Here is my code linking the html page to the js:
[image]

Here is the js code:
[image]

Comment: Flip the scripts as in put the `jquery.min.js` script before the `script.js`.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put jquery.min.js before script.js.